# Fresh Install Blender Lag/Delay

Tags: interface, 3d-view, installation

I just installed Blender for the first time, never used this software before and when I tried using it, it had a big delay between when I click something and the response, everything is lagging, moving the cube in the scenery takes 5 seconds before showing on screen. I get this error :

```
 Failed to set 44100hz, got 48000hz instead
```

I don't think this is the cause of my problem, but I hope it helps.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2261/blender-is-currently-unusable-on-nvidia-gpus-m-mx-family?cb=1

Comment: The `Failed to set 44100hz, got 48000hz instead` is just a Python message and is totally normal, happens at every Blender launch. It is unrelated to the lag you are experiencing